How to verify a certificate chain using WolfSSL
Assuming we have a certificate chain A->B->C with a depth of 3, where A is the root certificate.
At present, it appears that the WolfSSL command line supports verifying a certificate chain with a maximum depth of 2. Namely either:
wolfssl verify -CAfile A.crt B.crt

or
wolfssl verify -CAfile B.crt -partial_chain C.crt

But if I want to validate the complete A->B->C certificate chain at once, how should I do it? If it is indeed not possible to do this from the command line, could anyone share a code snippet using WolfSSL to accomplish this? Thanks a lot.
